# Switching over from selecting multiple values from array to a single value in PHP

Tags: php

I currently have a piece of code that is selecting multiple values from an array and was just wondering how I can switch it over to only picking a single value from an array.

So far I've tried changing `array_rand($status, rand(2,3))` to `array_rand($status, rand(1,1))` but it gives me the error message ** Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**. How can I resolve it?

```
$dateStart = new DateTime();
$dateStart->setDate(2012, 10, 01);
$dateEnd = new DateTime();
$dateEnd->setDate(2012, 12, 01);

$dates = array();
while ( $dateStart < $dateEnd ) {
   $rand = array_rand($status, rand(2,3));
   $text = '';
   foreach ( $rand as $key ) $text .= $status[$key] . '<br />';

   printf("<li><div id='activity_date'>%s</div>
           <div id='activity_box'>
           <div id='activity_text'>" . $text . ' request</div></div></li>',

   $dateStart->format("d/m/Y")
   );

   $dateStart->modify(sprintf("+%d day",mt_rand(1, 10)));
}
```

Comment: Do you know which array element will be used, or you want a random one? The `Foreach` is meant to only be used to cycle through an array and do something with each of them.

Comment: I want a random value from the array `$status`

Comment: Then @Gianps is correct, you could use `array_rand` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you want to keep your foreach, you have to ensure that you get an array back from `array_rand`.  One way would be like this:

```
$rand[] = array_rand($status);
foreach($rand as $key) { ... }
```

If you're always going to want only one random array member, then @Gianps has the better approach. Lose the `foreach`.

Comment: @methuselah: I'm not quite sure what you're asking me.  $rand is an array.  It holds one random key from $status. So it can be used with the `foreach` loop that you already have.

Comment: I've tried it but it keeps returning 2 values at certain points

Comment: @methuselah:  `$rand` will still be calculated every time you loop through your `while ( $dateStart < $dateEnd )` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rand = array_rand($status);
```

i feel myself a bit dumb.

change your code in this way:

```
$rand = array_rand($status);
$text = $status[$rand] . '<br />';
```

Comment: `array_rand` returns a scalar, not an array when only one key is requested. Foreach'ing a scalar results in the error he's seeing.

Comment: @dnagirl ok but for me is not correct to force it becoming an array, instead is better to change the code below (see my edit).

Comment: I agree, if he's sure he will only and always want one random result.

Comment: I've tried that and get the error message `Warning: Illegal offset type in ... on line 96. Notice: Undefined variable: text in ... on line 96`

Comment: @methuselah: `$text` is undefined because you haven't defined it before you tried to concatenate to it.